# Overloaded functions with overlapping typehints in signature results in error for mypy, but not pyright

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, pyright

Take the following example of code:

```py
from typing import Literal, overload, Tuple

SpecificStrings = Literal['bacon', 'eggs']

@overload
def my_func(foo: SpecificStrings) -> float:
    ...

@overload
def my_func(foo: str) -> bool:
    ...

def my_func(foo):
    if foo in ('bacon', 'eggs'):
        return 101.5
    else:
        return bool(foo)

def main() -> Tuple[float, bool]:
    x = my_func('bacon')  # float
    y = my_func('any other string')  # bool
    return x, y
```

The basic idea is that if `my_func` is called with a specific string `'bacon'` or `'eggs'` the return type should be a `float`. If any other string is used, the return type should be `bool`.

Intuitively, I would expect the *more specific* annotation (`foo: SpecificStrings`) to be checked first before the less specific `: str` annotation.

However, when type checking this file with `mypy`, I receive an error:

> t.py:6: error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types

Additionally, when type checking with `pyright`, there is no errors found.

It seems this could be a bug in `mypy`, a bug in `pyright`, or possibly something else...  [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id45) doesn't seem to indicate what the behavior should be in this scenario.

Is there another way to typehint this scenario such that it works (that is, such that `x` and `y` in the above example are understood as their respective types `float` and `bool`) with `mypy`?

---

**Edit:**

Interesting enough, using `Enum` instead of `Literal` seems to be a workaround:

```py
from enum import Enum

class SpecificStrings(Enum):
    bacon = 'bacon'
    eggs = 'eggs'
```

Using `reveal_type()` with pyright and mypy show the correct types in this scenario.

```
# pyright
C:\Users\path\to\t.py
  C:\Users\path\to\t.py:38:13 - information: Type of "x" is "float"
  C:\Users\path\to\t.pyt.py:39:13 - information: Type of "y" is "bool"
0 errors, 0 warnings, 2 informations
# mypy
t.py:38: note: Revealed type is "builtins.float"
t.py:39: note: Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
```

To me, this begs another question: why does `Enum` work but not `Literal`?

Frustratingly, however, PyCharm does not do the same thing:

[image: pycharm bad type]

Comment: This is a bug in `pyright` IMO, since your function can indeed return a float for a non-literal (`str`) input based on its runtime value.  You should type the second overload as returning `Union[float, bool]`.

Comment: @Samwise I considered the same thought. That might be the case. Although I tried using `Enum` instead of `Literal` and both mypy and pyright seem happy... that would seem to contradict the idea that the `Literal` should be considered an error. Does that make sense? (edited question with those details).

Comment: "using `Enum` instead of `Literal` seems to be a workaround" It doesn't, it just "fails" without an error. If you add ``reveal_type((x, y))`` you will see that you actually get a ``Tuple[bool, bool]`` – because none of the strings match the ``float`` case. However, ``bool`` is a valid ``int``  – and ``int`` is a valid ``float`` as per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower)! Change ``my_func`` to provide e.g. a ``str`` for each ``SpecificStrings`` and the enum case fails loudly as well.